# SQL to convert JSON object into array of objects in Posgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a column of JSON type in a postgres table. It currently has values like this

`{"value": "abc"}`

I want to write a SQL query that can change this to

`[{"value": "abc", "timestamp": 1465373673}]`

The part `timestamp: 1465373673` will be hard coded

Any ideas on how this SQL query can be written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use json_build_array and json_build_object:

```
UPDATE test 
set a = json_build_array(
          json_build_object('value', a->'value', 'timestamp', 1465373673)
        );
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=122b6bcb033f7bdfa6347f69c1ebed83).

Answer (score 2):

Use the concatenation operator and the function `jsonb_build_array()`:

```
select jsonb_build_array('{"value": "abc"}'::jsonb || '{"timestamp": 1465373673}');

              jsonb_build_array
---------------------------------------------
 [{"value": "abc", "timestamp": 1465373673}]
(1 row)
```

Read [JSON Functions and Operators.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)